# Sorting a 2D array in Coldfusion

Tags: arrays, sorting, coldfusion

I have an array that I would like to sort according to 2 values. The first one works fine but i cant seem to get the second one right

This is how I am sorting according to the first value:

```
<cfloop index="outer" from="1" to="#arrayLen(result)#">
    <cfloop index="inner" from="1" to="#arrayLen(result)-1#">
        <cfif result[inner][7] lt result[outer][7]>
            <cfset arraySwap(result,inner,outer)>
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>
</cfloop>
```

The second value that I would like to sort by is not a numeric value, it is a persons surname. It is the 2nd item in the array

How could I go about to sort by both these values in the array, both have to be descending. I also do not want to sort by the length of the persons surname but sort them alphabetically

Comment: Which version of ColdFusion?

Comment: I am using Coldfusion 10 at the moment Adam

Comment: Oh, and I should have asked before: what's the schema of the array?  It's difficult to infer it from your code. Either way, if the sorting criteria are complex, you'll need to use `arraySort()` with a callback (second syntax variation): https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySort

Comment: @Dave Adam is right. While my code did work for your scenario, a callback on arraysort is the superior (read: more efficient!) route. Certainly, if you're developing for CF10+, you should be using ArraySort(..) as Adam cited above and I've updated my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Adam Cameron points out, nested looping can get extremely heavy if you have large datasets. I'll leave my former code in place for people using older CFs.

However, if you have CF10/Railo 4 or above, the following code should work better for you. It produces exactly the same results while being faster.

As below, this still uses a basic mockup array and the second element vs the OP's seventh (in his more complex dataset).

```
<cfset Result = [["dan","smith"],["dan","Johnson"],["bob","jones"],["dan","smith"],["dan","johnson"],["bob","jones"],["cfquery","param"],["steve","buscemi"],["dan","smith"],["dan","johnson"],["bob","jones"]]>
  
<Cfset arraySort(result, function (current_element, next_element) {
    return comparenocase(current_element[2], next_element[2]);
  })>
  
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

You can take this a step (or many steps further) by comparing the first name too, or any other data.

```
<cfset Result = [["dan2","smith"],["dan1","Johnson"],["bob","jones"],["dan3","smith"],["dan0","johnson"],["bob","jones"],["cfquery","param"],["steve","buscemi"],["dan","smith"],["dan","johnson"],["bob","jones"]]>

<Cfset arraySort(result, function (current_element, next_element) {
    return comparenocase("#current_element[2]#, #current_element[1]#", "#next_element[2]#, #next_element[1]#");
  })>
  
<cfdump var="#result#">
```

### Update: People using older versions of CF wanting to replicate this may want to check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27257387/3917091) by user "Henry".

Comment: Only a lunatic would hand-roll a sorting algorithm. And this is a particularly leaden one, to boot. This is a terrible answer. Dave, you need to be a bit more discerning with your "accept answer" trigger. This is *not* an answer to your question.

Comment: @AdamCameron I took a minute and modified his code to do what he wanted. My answer does work, so I left it in place for the many people using CF9 or below or for newbies to see how code they're familiar with can be written more effectively.. However, if he intends to run this more than once, (which is very likely), you're very much right that a callback function is better. I did update my code with the example, and an example on how to easily it a step further.

Comment: Have a google for some common sorting algorithms, eg: Quick Sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quicksort) or Merge Sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort), or - blimey - even Bubble Sort (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bubble_sort). No answer to a sorting question should involve "rolling your own". This answer is professionally irresponsible.