# Sorting an implicit array of implicit structs by struct key

Tags: coldfusion, coldfusion-8

Based on the first [example in this blog post](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1641-learning-coldfusion-9-implicit-struct-and-array-usage.htm), I have an implicit array of implicit structs. My data is actually pretty similar, e.g.:

```
<cfset ReportsArray = [
  {
    Name = "My First Report",
    Group = "Group One"
  },
  {
    Name = "My Second Report",
    Group = "Group Two"
  },
  {
    Name = "My Third Report"
    Group = "Group One"
  },
  ...etc...
]>
```

I decided to create the data in this format so that I can later push a new report to the array in any group, or just rewrite the array with a new list of reports if needed. I'm wondering if it's possible to sort this array based on the "Group" key in the structs so that I can loop through them and output something like this:

**Group One**

My First Report

My Third Report

**Group Two**

My Second Report

--

Does that make sense? Or am I going about this wrong?

Comment: I'm so curious where your data actually comes from, what the source object is. It almost sounds, from your couple of comments, like this thing in the config file is a static object? If it's a case of a large static object that you need to sort once, you can use something execute something like this to create a sorted version of your object and generate the implicit sorted version of the code. You can run the code in this http://pastebin.com/5BVpKJB2 on www.cflive.net to quickly generate a sorted object. (If it's not static object, that's cool, it just sounded from your description like it is).

Comment: I'm not sure I understand how to answer your question, but I'll try to explain further what I'm doing. (I'm also in no way confident my way is the best approach, as I'm mostly a front-end developer.) I have a centralized reporting application at /applications/Reporting/. I also have many client instances of this app on my server at /ClientName/Admin/Reporting/. Both locations have a config .cfm file that sets up the basic app configuration. /applications/Reporting/ has the default config, and the one at the client level just modifies or adds any additional configuration.

Comment: ...so in this case, the config at /applications/Reporting/ has a default list of reports that apply to all clients. However, the config file in /ClientOne/Admin/Reporting/ might either rewrite the entire array of reports (<cfset ReportsArray = [...]>) OR could just append some new one's (<cfset ArrayAppend(ReportsArray, ...>). In most cases I'd like to be able to append only the custom one's I need instead of rewriting and maintaining that huge ReportsArray in every client directory. So in that case the array won't always be in alpha order, and I'll have to be able to re-sort it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe Query would be the right data type for the right job?  with ColdFusion's famous Query of Queries, sorting data like this is a piece of cake.

If you really want to sort an array of objects, and you're in CF10+, you are in luck.  You may use ArraySort with callback: https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/ArraySort.

If you insist, here's a easy to read bubble sort that would work in CF8:

```
<cfscript>

    function sortReports(reports) 
    {
        var local = {};

        local.sorted = false;
        local.reportSize = arrayLen(reports);

        while (!local.sorted) 
        {
            local.sorted = true;
            for (local.i = 1; local.i < local.reportSize ; local.i = local.i + 1) 
            {
                local.report1 = reports[local.i];
                local.report2 = reports[local.i + 1];

                if (local.report1.group > local.report2.group)
                {
                    arraySwap(reports, local.i, local.i + 1);
                    local.sorted = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return reports;
    }

reportsArray = [
  {
    Name = "My First Report",
    Group = "Group One"
  },
  {
    Name = "My Second Report",
    Group = "Group Two"
  },
  {
    Name = "My Third Report",
    Group = "Group One"
  }
];
</cfscript>
<cfdump var="#sortReports(reportsArray)#">
```

Run it here: http://www.trycf.com/scratch-pad/pastebin?id=RuSHgZYq

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. All I really need is a human-readable collection of data that I can overwrite or modify, so if I can do that with QueryNew (that's what you're suggesting with query of queries, right?) then that's great.My dev server is CF10, but my production server is CF8. I haven't used QueryNew yet, but hopefully CF8 won't be a huge pain.

Comment: This is nice, plus 1. This kind of makes me wonder where the data is actually even coming from.  @Michael what is the source of the data, it was very awesome for you to give us a sample data to work with, but what's the source of this data actually? Obviously, it's not a static object.

Comment: I agree Q of a Q is a nice tool. It will not perform any worse than the loop offereed by cfqueryparam - and will give you cleaner code. Just my opinion.  Like cfqueryparam I'd like to know where your data is coming from? You storing it _in the code_ or from mongo or couchbase as json?  it seems like table data to me.

Comment: More on the data...I'm creating a centralized reporting app that contains a default set of reports that are applicable to all our clients. Every client calls an instance of this app with a config file that can extend or overwrite the default reports with their own. The reports are just links to custom .cfm files that are either at the centralized or instance root (there's a "File" key in my structs that I omitted from my example above). I'd like this data to be in a db, but it seemed silly to create an admin app to manage these reports when I can just specify them in a config. Make sense?

Comment: @Michael Henry's update makes this a great answer in every single respect. My solution would loop over it ArrayLen * ArrayLen - 1 times (72 for a 9 element array), every time, where Henry's will  loop over it as few times as possible (If the data were already sorted, it would loop over it ArrayLen - 1 times, where mine will still go 72 times). This is better.

Answer (score 4):

There's a [`quicksort()` function on CFLib](http://www.cflib.org/udf/quicksort) which takes a comparator callback, just use that to sort your array.

You'll need to write the comparator function, but it's just this:

```
function reportComparator(e1, e2){
    return compare(e1.group, e2.group);
}
```